# Precision in rotating images

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

I searched a code to rotate an image in C#, and found this to be almost perfect. It does the job while keeping the same Height and Width properties of my old photo and maintaining its quality.
But, could you improve the code to make it more precise. For example when I send an angle of 0.0001 It doesn't seem to rotate it! (I really need to be so precise in this step)

```
public static Image RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
    turn the Bitmap into a Graphics object
    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    gfx.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2);
    gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);
    gfx.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2);
    gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gfx.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));
    gfx.Dispose();
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: This method is only responsible for creating one image at a time - the problem is probably in the code that calls this method (and does not `Dispose()` the resulting image after saving it to disk?).

Comment: Not related to your problem, but: Do not call Dispose on your local `gfx` disposable like that. Use the `using` statement block for this.

Comment: Please also refrain from asking multiple questions in a single question. If you have two problems (one about memory consumption, another about rotating) then create/ask two separate questions.

Comment: @Ahmad. If you rotate by 0.0001 degree you won't be able to do that even with photoshop. if your image is 10,000 pixel wide, the last pixel on the right will have to go up by 0.0175 pixel. you would need an image of 1,000,000 pixel wide so that 0.0001 degree up by 1 pixel and it wouldn't be visible to the human eye yet. Just checked and 1,000,000 pixel the last one will end up exactly 1.7453 pixel higher

Comment: By the way, if you rotate a vector of 1 meter length by 0.0001 degrees, the resulting difference in position would only be about 2 **micrometers**! How large (width/height) do you think your pictures would need to be to yield an observable difference when rotating by such a miniscule amount?

Comment: @elgonzo why should I do that, Please provide some info so I could learn (What's the difference)

Comment: @Franck So I have an A4 scanned Image of 300dp. so what is smallest degree that I could rotate my image to take effect? (Instead of sending all images to this function, It's better to avoid the process of some which won't have any effect)!

Comment: One problem, one question, one answer each. Different people have different fields of expertise, so they look at or ignore different kind of questions. Also, the problems you are asking about might already have a duplicate question/answer here, so asking your questions separately makes it easier to flag and redirect your question to the duplicate question/answer in case such exist.

Comment: @elgonzo I am new here so thanks for pointing that, Let's focus on the part of precision only? could you provided me with the formula which gave you 0.0175 pixel as an answer?

Comment: Look up "angular diameter" ;-) Given a distance and an angle in degrees (angular diameter), the real diameter (the "width of the angle" at the given distance)  is calculated as 2*distance*tan(angle/2)

Comment: @Ahmad the pixel of 0.0175 was derived from calculating with the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) and i reconfirmed using AutoCAD to rotate a line by that amount of degree using 1 unit per pixel

Comment: How could I find the pixel wide for my image?

Comment: @Ahmad A4 at 300 dpi the longer side will be 3508 pixels. to have a denivelation of 1 pixel (smallest possible increment) which mean the right most pixel will be 1 pixel higher than the left one which is not visible to the human eye again is 0.0163 degree angle

Comment: _turn the Bitmap into a Graphics object_ This is not at all what is happening. you only __associate that Graphics object to a bitmap__ so it will work on it.

Comment: Why do you think it is not rotating? You have such a small angle, I do not believe you can see it by eyr.